# find length of sum of vectors

Tags: vectors

Given: a=vector a, b=vector b, |a|=3, |b|=2,angle between them is 150 degrees. I have to calculate |4a+3b|.Which formula should I use? I am thinking of|4a+3b|=sqrt((4a+3b)*(4a+3b)).Is it correct? If not, please provide a correct formula.

Comment: Yes it is correct.

Comment: @AnneBauval  Thanks.